# Please, how do i convert a list of stings to a long string separated with comma in python

Tags: python, string, list

#For instance, I have the following list of strings:

s = [['my name Daniel'], ['my name Doe'], ['Your name is Philip'], ['His name is John']]

#Please, how do I convert this to a long comma separated strings?

Comment: Can you tell the expected output ?

Comment: 'my name Daniel, my name Doe, Your name is Philip, His name is John'

Comment: @AbidAhmad that is the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of lists of strings.

You'll need to flatten that list to just a list of strings. One way of doing this is to use list comprehension.

```
s = [['my name Daniel'], ['my name Doe'], ['Your name is Philip'], ['His name is John']]
new_s = [string for sublist in s for string in sublist]
result = ",".join(new_s)
```

This should get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked with slight modification of your codes.

s = [['my name Daniel'], ['my name Doe'], ['Your name is Philip'], ['His name is John']]
new_s = [string for sublist in s for string in sublist]
result = ", ".join(new_s)
result

Comment: Ohh yes I'm sorry that was a typo. I have corrected it in my answer. If this worked for you please give me an upvote and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the extra square brackets, and use `join()`.

```py
s = ['my name Daniel', 'my name Doe', 'Your name is Philip', 'His name is John']

print(','.join(s))
```

Prints:

```
my name Daniel,my name Doe,Your name is Philip,His name is John
```

Comment: Ok.but how do I get rid of the extra square brackets without manually doing?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for as mentioned is the `.join()`. You also shouldn't have a more dimensional tuple. So your code should be:

```
list = ['my name Daniel', 'my name Doe', 'Your name is Philip', 'His name is John']
print(", ".join(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [['my name Daniel'], ['my name Doe'], ['Your name is Philip'], ['His name is John']]

s = [sublist[0] for sublist in s] # get the first and only element of sublist
result = ",".join(s)
```